# Does setting up SSL for Azure devops on permises impact already configured deployment group agents using http

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ssl-certificate, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

We have Azure devops setup using http and planning to move to https. As Deployment group agent targets has been setup using http site, does it impact the deployments using deployment group agents ?

Deployment group agents has been configured on servers using PowerShell referring to http site , does it mean we need to reconfigure the agents?

Comment: Does Azure allow you direct access to  Internet Information Services? (IIS)?  If it does there are a couple of ways to do it automatically.  If yes, let me know and I can give you some options.  If my question is NO you can not access IIS, then jesse answer seems like the answer.  But if you CAN access the IIS there are a couple settings to force all the http requests into https so you don't have to update each and every thing by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to reconfigure all agents.

Basically the Project Collection Uri for your instance will change.